# How to find the area of an arbitrary shape contained within a circle using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an arbitrary shape, of which the exterior boundary has been traced in MATLAB using `bwboundaries`. Using `regionprops`, I can calculate the total area enclosed by this shape.

However, I want to know the area for *only* the parts of the shape that fall within a circle of known radius `R` centered at coordinates `[x1, y1]`. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: and what is your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to approach this. One way you could alter the mask *before* performing `bwboundaries` (or `regionprops`) so that it *only* includes pixels which are within the given circle.

This example assumes that you already have a logical matrix `M` that you pass to `bwboundaries`.

```
function [A, boundaries] = traceWithinCircle(M, x1, y1, R);

    %// Get pixel centers
    [x,y] = meshgrid(1:size(M, 1), 1:size(M, 2));

    %// Compute their distance from x1, y1
    distances = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, [x(:), y(:)], [x1, y1]).^2, 2));

    %// Determine which are inside of the circle with radius R
    isInside = distances <= R;

    %// Set the values outside of this circle in M to zero
    %// This will ensure that they are not detected in bwboundaries
    M(~isInside) = 0;

    %// Now perform bwboundaries on things that are 
    %// inside the circle AND were 1 in M
    boundaries = bwboundaries(M);

    %// You can, however, get the area by simply counting the number of 1s in M
    A = sum(M(:));

    %// Of if you really want to use regionprops on M
    %// props = regionprops(M);
    %// otherArea = sum([props.Area]);
end
```

And as an example

```
%// Load some example data
data = load('mri');
M = data.D(:,:,12) > 60;

%// Trace the boundaries using the method described above
B = traceWithinCircle(M, 70, 90, 50);

%// Display the results
figure;
hax = axes();
him = imagesc(M, 'Parent', hax);
hold(hax, 'on');
colormap gray
axis(hax, 'image');

%// Plot the reference circle
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
plot(x1 + cos(t)*R, y1 + sin(t)*R);

%// Plot the segmented boundaries
B = bwboundaries(M);

for k = 1:numel(B)
    plot(B{k}(:,2), B{k}(:,1), 'r');
end
```

[image]